Mockito Test Throwing Exceptions
I am fairly new to spring boot. I am trying to test this service class if it throws the IllegalArgumentException.class but somehow the exception is not thrown. Help me get what I am missing. This is a section of the service class:
   public ResponseEntity<ModelApiResponse> createResponse(Response response)
            throws JsonProcessingException, IllegalArgumentException{
        try{
            chatResponseRepository.save(response);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.valueOf(GlobalVariables.RESPONSE_CODE_201));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.valueOf(GlobalVariables.RESPONSE_CODE_500));
        }
    }

I have tried two test methods. The test method (1):
  @Test
    public void testThatResponseCreationThrowsErrorWhenSavingFails() throws Exception{
        Response responseMock = mock(Response.class);
        when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(new Response())).thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);

        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> abbyResponseRepositoryMock.save(abbyResponseMock));

    }

Test method two:
   @Test
    public void testThatResponseCreationThrowsErrorWhenSavingFails() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(new Response())).thenThrow(Mockito.mock(IllegalArgumentException.class));

        Response response = new Response();
        Response.setMessage("This is a unit test response message");
        Response.setNxtMessageId("98765");

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/responses/create-response")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + "credentials")
                .header(GlobalVariables.X_CORRELATION_ID, "123456")
                .header(GlobalVariables.X_SOURCE_APP, "source_app")
                .header(GlobalVariables.X_USER, "user")
                .header(GlobalVariables.X_USER_ROLE, "user")
                .content(this.json(response))
                .contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.header.responseCode", is(500)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.header.responseMessage", is("Error saving chat response")))
                .andReturn();
    }

Also advise on which test method would be suitable. The controller is just a basic controller class that calls the service class to save a chat response. The service class on the other hand calls the repository to save the chat response.
output:
Expected: is <500>
     but: was <201>


The stubbed method:
when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(new Response()))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);

can never match the call
abbyResponseRepositoryMock.save(abbyResponseMock)

because abbyResponseMock is never equal to new Response().
You have two possibilities:

Change the stub to throw on any response instance:

when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(any()))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);

This will match null too; if you only want to match any non-null Response instances, match with any(Response.class).

Match the expected instance in the stub:

when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(abbyResponseMock))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);

or
when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(eq(abbyResponseMock)))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);


In your second test, you are serializing the response to JSON and your application is then deserializing it again. So you can either again change the stub to match any() response instances, implement equals() in your Response class, or use the argThat matcher:
when(chatResponseRepositoryMock.save(argThat(res -> {
      return "This is a unit test response message".equals(res.getMessage())
        && "98765".equals(res.getNxtMessageId());
    })))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);

